# Update a greasemonkey script in chrome without reinstalling?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, greasemonkey

I just want to be able to save, refresh the page, and have my changes show up like I do in Firefox. Having to drag it over and install it every time gets annoying.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13):

Yes, there is a way to do this.  Using the method adopted from [this brilliant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258989/manually-adding-a-userscript-to-google-chrome/5259212#5259212) (^_^), you can edit scripts -- in place -- and just hit a "Reload" link for the changes to take effect.

This method has the added bonus that Chrome's [Extensions folder](http://www.timeatlas.com/5_minute_tips/annoyances/how_to_uninstall_google_chrome_extensions)<sup>1</sup> doesn't get cluttered with indecipherable folder and file names, and you can easily find the script you want to tweak.

**Here's how to set up your work environment to allow easy script updating:**

1. Create a directory that's convenient to you, and *not where Chrome normally looks for extensions*<sup>1</sup>.   For example, Create: `C:\MyChromeScripts\`.
   This will be where all your scripts will reside in the future.
2. For each script create its own subdirectory.   For example, `Script_1`, `Script_2`, etc.
3. Each subdirectory should contain its script, EG `MyScript1.user.js`, and any files used by that script.
4. Now for the secret sauce... You must also create a manifest file in that subdirectory, and it must be named: `manifest.json`.

   Sample contents, at a minimum:

   ```
   {
       "manifest_version": 2,
       "content_scripts": [ {
           "exclude_globs":    [  ],
           "include_globs":    [ "*" ],
           "js":               [ "MyScript1.user.js" ],
           "matches":          [   "https://stackoverflow.com/*",
                                   "https://stackoverflow.com/*"
                               ]
       } ],
       "description":  "This script does X, Y, and Z.",
       "name":         "My script number 1",
       "version":      "1"
   }
   ```
5. Now, in Chrome's Extension manager (URL = *chrome://extensions/*), Expand ***Developer mode***.
6. Click the ***Load unpacked extension...*** button.
7. For the folder, paste in the **folder** for your script, For example:
   `C:\MyChromeScripts\Script_1`.
8. Your script will be installed and operational.
9. Keep the *Extensions* page open.  Now, when you save any changes to your *.js file, Hit the ***Reload*** link for them to take effect immediately.
10. Enjoy!

---

<sup>1</sup> The extensions folder defaults to:

```
Windows XP:
C:\Documents and Settings\***{username}***\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

Windows Vista:
C:\Users\***{username}***\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

Windows 7:
C:\Users\***{username}***\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
```

Although you can change it by running Chrome with the `--user-data-dir=` option.

Comment: This is great, is there a way to watch the directory though? I still need to navigate back to the extensions page.

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski, Not that I'm aware of, but haven't kept up with Chrome changes since they borked native userscripts.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that if you have somewhere server where you can import your changed file.

Like this

```
// a function that loads jQuery and calls a callback function when jQuery has finished loading
function addJQuery(callback) {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.setAttribute("src", "http://server.url/Custom/jquery.min.js");
  script.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.textContent = "(" + callback.toString() + ")();";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }, false);
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

function addScript(callback) {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.setAttribute("src", "http://server.url/Custom/Custom script.js");
  script.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.textContent = "(" + callback.toString() + ")();";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }, false);
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

// load jQuery and execute the init function
addJQuery(addScript);
```

This loads first jQuery then my custom script, when i run the webpage it always reloads the whole script.

Maybe this helps you too.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to reinstall the script, you can restart chrome.
This should make your changes to take effect.

I agree this is very annoying

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is to use two files:

- A `userscript.user.js` with GM headers which loads `script.js`. You can make it purge the cache every day (tell it to load `script.js` with a random query string added)
- `script.js` which contains the actual script.

For example, I've done that [here](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/blob/master/StackExchange/MathJaxButtons.user.js)

```
//#!userscript.user.js

// ==UserScript==
//GM headers
// ==/UserScript==


(function(){
     var d=new Date();
     var script = document.createElement("script");
     script.type = "text/javascript";
     script.src="script.js?purge="+d.getMonth()+""+d.getDay(); //appends a new query string every day. This evades browser cache
     document.body.appendChild(script); //you can append to `head` as well, I used body here sine I needed jQuery already loaded
})();
```

The script loads `script.js?purge=xyz`, where `xyz` depends on the date. The purge query string makes sure that the script is only cached for a day and not more--by next day, it will be loaded afresh. For development uses, `"script.js?purge="+Math.random()` is better. If the script is on your local machine though, you need not worry about the cache for yourself.

Now, if you make a change to `script.js`, by tomorrow everyone will be using the updated version.