# Editing Chrome extension javascript in-place

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, greasemonkey

I'm used to making Greasemonkey scripts for Firefox, where I can edit the script while it's in the user profile, refresh, and see changes immediately.

I know that Chrome supports Greasemonkey scripts without needing the actual Greasemonkey plugin. Is it possible to do the same in-place script editing? If so, what is the path to the extension script?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update a greasemonkey script in chrome without reinstalling?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884794/update-a-greasemonkey-script-in-chrome-without-reinstalling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you edit the extension in the default directory structure, changes and especially additions are wiped the next time Chrome restarts.

But if you [setup a custom work environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884794/update-a-greasemonkey-script-in-chrome-without-reinstalling/5268889#5268889), then you can edit-in-place, quite nicely.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884794/update-a-greasemonkey-script-in-chrome-without-reinstalling/5268889#5268889).

Answer (score 2):

You can go to developer tools, and use the 'Scripts' tab to directly edit the source of scripts. On Mac, Command + S works to "save" the script, although it doesn't seem to persist anywhere that I can find. I usually set a breakpoint since that seems to make chrome retain my changes even after a page refresh.

Comment: Eh, it's better than nothing... although clearly, the plugin itself is persisted somewhere. That's what I'm after.

Comment: Sorry, then because I clearly misunderstood the question. I don't think I can help at all then. =(